# How to make search term stick in box after POST and after cliking after that

Tags: php, html, mysql

Does anyone know how to make a search term stick into the search after the POST is made, which is my current method. I need the search term to stick in the searchbox even after clicking on somthing else in the site. Here is my current code-

```
<input type="text" name="searchterm" <?php if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])){echo 'value="'.$_POST['searchterm'].'"';} ?>>
```

I need it to stick their until its changed again

Below is my php code for the action

```
      <?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$_SESSION["search_fields_value"] = $_POST;
$searchterm  = $_POST['searchterm'];
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions  WHERE id LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR date LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR propertydescription LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR transactiontype LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR applicabledocument LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR received LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR paid LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR toJLP LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR agentclient LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
$query="SELECT * FROM transactions" ;
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Read up on PHP Sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the `$_POST` values in `session`. So you can use in `pagination` also.

In search action section,

```
$_SESSION["search_fields_value"] = $_POST;
```

In search view form

```
$existing_values = array("search_term"=>"");// to use in the first time before search 
if(isset($_SESSION["search_fields_value"]))
  $existing_values = $_SESSION["search_fields_value"];
```

In your form,

```
<input type="text" name="searchterm" value='<?php echo $existing_values ['searchterm']; ?>'>
```

Comment: For actions section, do you mean for where the action for the search happens and Im not sure what you mean "in search view form"

Comment: Yes. Action means where the search happens. Search view form means where searchterm textbox exist.

Comment: I tried this but there is a small problem. When you search, it does the search, BUT when you search somthing new, it does not update until you refresh the page

Comment: Are you doing search with ajax? or normal form submit?

Comment: Normal, I will add my code to my first post

Comment: search form exist on same page or in separate page? Add the search code also.

Comment: The code I added is for the search, same page. The search is updating the table with the results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43847/discussion-between-kumar-v-and-a-r)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessions` on server side, or use a client-side solution like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)